# How do you left-align the pagination buttons on the toolbar of a listview in Cloud v10?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

In version 8 InsuranceSuite the pagination controls were left-aligned and always visible on the screen. With version 10 the pagination controls are now right-aligned and depending on table size they move around or you have to scroll to see them.

How can we put the pagination controls back on the left-hand side? Screenshots of v8 versus v10 attached.

I have tried setting the "Left align top toolbars" under Options --> Settings but it does not affect the pagination controls which remain on the right-hand side.

[image: v8-Pagination_on_Left]

[image: v10_Pagination_on_Right]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the Guidewire documentation and I find no mention of a way to change this functionality. It appears to be a design choice from Guidewire. There is a property on the ListView widget called bottomPaging which duplicates the paging buttons on the bottom of the ListView, but the paging buttons would still be on the right of the screen unfortunately.

I would suggest changing the width of the column that is causing the PCF to render such a wide page size. In version 10 when a user changes the width of a column this value is remembered for that user as a preference across sessions and devices. So if this is a problem just for 1 user it could be fixed this way.

Comment: Second this. I don't think there's a way to override this design choice by guidewire

Comment: Thanks I've made multiple efforts asking Guidewire directly through their community forum, creating a case, via email, etc... Responses  have been evasive at best. They won't confirm it's not possible to override this but I think you're correct. Appreciate your input.